# How to do type checking for Action methods parameters in Vuex with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, parameters, vuex

I'm trying to check the types that the parameters of the vuex action methods receive by calling these methods from within the vue component.
But eslint can't find the defined types of parameters in the vuex store file.

*Vuex store file*

```
actions: {
  updateFilter({ commit }, value: Filter) {
    commit("setFilter", value);
  }
},
mutations: {
  setFilter(state, value: Filter) {
    state.filter = value;
  }
}
```

*Vue component*

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions(["updateFilter"]),
  updateList() {
    // Here is where i can't check the parameter typing
    this.updateFilter(newData);
  }
}
```

Is there any way to check these types?

Comment: There's no straightforward way without typing mapped actions manually, that's one of reasons why Pinia may be preferred